# Do Net:HTTP calls/results in Rails get cached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-http

If I load a section of my website with Net::HTTP in Rails, will this get loaded every time or will it get cached along with the rest of the footer?

EDIT: I mean the rest of the footer is currently cached. Would the Net:HTTP results, which get rendered inside the footer, also become cached? I would like it to reload the results every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `Net::HTTP` will not cache anything for you. You will have to implement caching, or use a gem that does it for you. But depending on what you do with Rails, Rails can do it - look into fragment caching.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it does, at least not [by default](http://www.ericson.net/content/2011/04/caching-http-requests-with-ruby/) as of 2011. There's also a segment in the net/http.rb file in the ruby source that has the following code commented out:

```
 # The following example performs a conditional GET using the
  # If-Modified-Since header.  If the files has not been modified since the
  # time in the header a Not Modified response will be returned.  See RFC 2616
  # section 9.3 for further details.
  #
     uri = URI('http://example.com/cached_response')
     file = File.stat 'cached_response'

     req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
     req['If-Modified-Since'] = file.mtime.rfc2822

     res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
       http.request(req)
     }

     open 'cached_response', 'w' do |io|
       io.write res.body
     end if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
```

The source file is dated July 9. Hope that helps.